# I can't login to wordpress dashboard without SSH

Tags: login, wp-login-form, ssh

My friend gave me a username and a password to his wordpress site. Now when I try to login to the dashboard, it tells me I have the wrong username or password. He also gave me a SSH port number and a username and password for SSH. Now I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I can't seem to log in to the dashboard. I know I have to use the SSH credentials and port number but I don't how because I am a beginner at wordpress. I've tried searching for the problem but I haven't been successful in finding the right answers. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried resetting password using "Forgot password" option?

Comment: Have you tried asking your friend?  General WordPress support is off-topic here.  [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Check wordpress [Login Trouble codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble) step by step. I hope you didn't make any change which affect to code(i.e. Add new plugin, .htaccess code change).

Let me know if you still facing same.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is to reset the password via phpMyAdmin.

**Step 1:** Identify the Name of your Database;

The best place to look is your wp-config.php file which is located in your root WordPress Directory. In there you will find the name of your database.

**Step 2:** Go to your Control Panel (cPanel, from your hosting) and open phpMyAdmin;
[image]

Once you are in phpMyAdmin, you will need to select the correct database on the left hand side. Look for the name that you found in your wp-config.php and click on that. You will see a list of tables with a prefix wp_ for the most part.

Search for the table **wp_users**, click on it and then click on the Browse Tab.

**Step 3:** Locate the username(for example, **admin**)
When you see the username click on the Pencil (Edit) Icon to reset your Password.

**Step 4:** Now you will see a field that looks like this:
[image]
There is a user_pass field. Click on it to edit it.

**Step 5:** Set the password.

You will notice that there are a lot of random characters in the password field. Due to security reasons, WordPress stores the passwords as **MD5 Hash** rather than Plain text.

This means that you will not be able to enter plain text as the password. You would need to use one of the MD5 generators online to generate your password.

**Step 6** Generate a new MD5 password hash.
Go to [Javascript MD5](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/) and generate a new password. Simply type your password in that tool and generate MD5 results. Copy and paste the code you get from the converter into your phpMyAdmin field and click Go to save changes.

*You have now successfully changed your WordPress Password from phpMyAdmin.*